# Speed Up Finding Number of Elements Between Values Matlab

Tags: matlab

I've created what is a fairly simple MATLAB script to simulate the behaviour discussed in [this question over on Maths SE.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3858190/normalising-low-duty-cycle-random-data/3859897#3859897)

```matlab
clearvars;
samples = 1000;
x = 256;
r=exprnd(1/20e6,1,samples); % Generate exponentially distributed randoms.
endTime = sum(r);
quickMean=sum(r(1:x))/x; % Quick calc the mean and median.
quickMedian=0.693 * quickMean;
p = cumsum(r); % Convert event deltas into timestamps
bitstream = false(1,samples);
time = 0;
lastTime = 0;
for i = 1:samples
    lastTime = time;
    time = time + quickMedian;
    if (numel(p(p < time & p > lastTime)) > 0)
        bitstream(i) = true;
    end
    if (time > p(end))
        break
    end
end
ratio = sum(bitstream)/samples;
```

The script seems to work, however, if I use a large number of samples (say a million), which would be beneficial, it really crawls.

I'm assuming that the problematic statement is this one:

`p(p < time & p > lastTime)`

Is there a more efficient way to check if any elements in an array fall between two values?

Comment: `if any(p(p < time) > lastTime)` seems to speed it up a bit, but it still gets a bit sluggish. I'm sure that it would be possible to use some creative indexing to limit the number of elements in `p` that you're searching (you can use the last index of `p < time` from the previous iteration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, we can use the fact that `p` is monotonically increasing and ignore values less than `lastTime`. If we find the last value for which `p < time`, only the values to the right can be greater than* `time` on the next iteration (`lastTime`).

```
clearvars;
samples = 1000;
x = 256;
r=exprnd(1/20e6,1,samples); % Generate exponentially distributed randoms.
endTime = sum(r);
quickMean=sum(r(1:x))/x; % Quick calc the mean and median.
quickMedian=0.693 * quickMean;
p = cumsum(r); % Convert event deltas into timestamps
bitstream = false(1,samples);
time = 0;
lastTime = 0;

% code is the same up to here ---

lastTimeIdx = 1; % index of (last value < lastTime) + 1
for i = 1:samples
    lastTime = time;
    time = time + quickMedian;

    valsInRange = p(lastTimeIdx:end) < time; % p > lastTime & p < time
    timeIdx = find(valsInRange, 1, 'last'); % returns [] or index

    if ~isempty(timeIdx)
        bitstream(i) = true;
        lastTimeIdx = lastTimeIdx + timeIdx; % update start of next search
    end
    if (time > p(end))
        break
    end
end
ratio = sum(bitstream)/samples;
```

<sub>*Actually, this is "greater than or equal to", but since the values of `p` are unique, they are the same thing.</sub>

---

Okay, I just tried `histc` in Octave. I'm embarrassed to say that it's ridiculously fast. Like 4 orders of magnitude faster. Here's the code I used, but `histc` is deprecated in MATLAB, and the binning for `histcounts` is different, so you may have to play with it a bit.

```
bitstream_hist = histc(p, [0:samples]*quickMedian) > 0;
bitstream_hist = bitstream_hist(1:samples);
```

One million samples finishes in a fraction of a second. Sorry I didn't think of this sooner.

Comment: You can also get rid of most of those repeated *O(n)* operations, but they're trivial compared to the *O(n^3)* loop.

Comment: I just had a thought in the shower (where all the best ideas come from) that this is simply a histogram. I'll try that out when I get a chance, but since I use Octave rather than MATLAB, the functions and the timings will not be at all the same.

Answer (score 3):

Let’s examine that whole expression:

```
numel(p(p < time & p > lastTime)) > 0
```

We can separate that out for clarity:

```
I = p < time & p > lastTime;
tmp = p(I);
n = numel(tmp);
n > 0
```

Here, the creation of `tmp` is pretty expensive: it looks at where `I` is true, and it copies those elements over to a new array. But the only thing you do with this array is seeing how many elements it has. Logically `n` will be equal to the number of true elements in `I`. And you don’t really need this number, you just need to know if it’s larger than 0. That is, you want to know if any of the elements in `I` is true. You can do so with `any`:

```
any(p < time & p > lastTime)
```

Comment: Ahh, I wasn't aware of the existence of `any()` this seems to have helped somewhat. Thanks!